# How I can pause a thread for some time in python?

Tags: python-3.x, button, thread-safety, python-multithreading, ttk

I am working for build a software where I wan't to pause/stop a thread for some time or for a event
here are some essential code to understand you better

```
self.staff_list_thread = Thread(target = self.get_staff_list, kwargs = {"master": self.frame_staff_list}, daemon = True)
self.staff_list_thread.start()

def get_staff_list(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
    def add_staff_button_callback():
        self.get_add_staff(self.frame_staff_add)

    def detail_edit_staff_button_callback(email):
        if email is not None:
            self.get_detail_edit_staff(self.frame_staff_detail, email)

    row = 1
    self.staff_introduction = get_a_label(master, text="This is staff area", row=0, column=0, padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10))
    self.staff_introduction.config(style="Title.TLabel")
    self.add_staff_button = get_a_button(master, text="Add New Staff", row=0, column=1, padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10), ipadx=7, ipady=4)
    self.add_staff_button.config(command=add_staff_button_callback)

    staffs = self.get_staff_queryset()
    if staffs is not None:
        for staff in staffs:
                self.staff_data_button = get_a_button(master, text='{} as {}'.format(staff[1], staff[5]), row=row, column=0, padx=(0, 0), pady=(5, 5), ipadx=10, ipady=10, relief=FLAT, use_ttk=False)
                self.staff_data_button.config(command = lambda email=staff[2]: detail_edit_staff_button_callback(email))
                row = row + 1
```

In the end of function I wan't to end of pause the thread and when the new staff is added I wan't to recount or reset the list with current data so I need to run thread again
Here are the button call func

```
def get_add_staff(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
    self.add_staff_current = True
    if self.have_one_detail:
        # self.destroy_child(self.frame_staff_detail)
        self.have_one_detail = False
        self.frame_staff_detail.destroy()
        self.frame_staff_detail         = get_a_frame(self.staff_add_update_panedwindow, column=1, sticky="wn")

    FullName, Email, Phone, Joining, Designation, Active = self.get_staff_variable()

    def cancel_new_staff_button_callback():
        # self.destroy_child(master)
        self.frame_staff_detail.destroy()
        self.frame_staff_detail         = get_a_frame(self.staff_add_update_panedwindow, column=1, sticky="wn")
        self.add_staff_current = False

    def staff_button_callback():
        data = {
            'full_name': FullName.get(),
            'email': Email.get(),
            'phone': float(Phone.get()),
            'joining': Joining.get(),
            'designation': Designation.get(),
            'responsibility': self.add_staff_responsibility_data.get(1.0, 'end'),
            'about': self.add_staff_about_data.get(1.0, 'end'),
            'active': Active.get()
        }
        execute = self.execute_staff_data(data=data)
        if execute is True:
            # self.staff_list_thread.start()
            cancel_new_staff_button_callback()

    self.get_staff_labels(master)

    self.add_staff_fullname_data                = get_a_entry(master, textvariable=FullName, width=36, row=1, column=1)
    self.add_staff_email_data                   = get_a_entry(master, textvariable=Email, row=2, width=36, column=1)
    self.add_staff_phone_data                   = get_a_entry(master, textvariable=Phone, row=3, column=1)
    self.add_staff_joining_data                 = get_a_entry(master, textvariable=Joining, row=4, column=1)
    self.add_staff_designation_data             = get_a_entry(master, textvariable=Designation, width=36, row=5, column=1)
    self.add_staff_responsibility_data          = get_a_text(master, width=36, height=4, row=6, column=1)
    self.add_staff_about_data                   = get_a_text(master, width=36, height=10, row=7, column=1)
    self.add_staff_active_data                  = get_a_radio(master, text="Active", variable=Active, value=1, row=8, column=1)
    self.add_staff_inactive_data                = get_a_radio(master, text="Inactive", variable=Active, value=0, row=9, column=1)

    self.save_new_staff_button                  = get_a_button(master, text="Add Staff", row=10, padx=(20, 20), pady=(30, 30))
    self.cancel_new_staff_button                = get_a_button(master, text="Cancel", row=10, column=1, padx=(20, 20), pady=(30, 30))
    self.save_new_staff_button.config(command=staff_button_callback)
    self.cancel_new_staff_button.config(command=cancel_new_staff_button_callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply answer your title question, you can pause a thread with the `time.sleep()`

```
import time
time.sleep(30) #pause for 30 seconds
```

With a naive implementation, you could just run this on a loop checking if the function should be called. Be careful that this will lock the whole paused thread.

From the code though I don't really understand where you want to pause it.

To react to an event, pausing a thread is not the right question, you need to implement a subscribe/register and callback logic.

Comment: OK, I'm giving a brief description,

Comment: OK, I'm giving a brief description, At the first time get_staff_list() function can list my staffs, but when I'm adding someone or deleting or updating I want to change my listed data real time, My logic is at the first time the function hooked into the thread and thread started so the staff listed, also when I'm executing any SQL I want to run thread again, then my listed data can change if data changed, If I can't stop thread and run again in specific function this is impossible, It's my main problem

Comment: Yeah, sounds like what you're asking the wrong question. You need to trigger this function when there's some kind of CRUD. Truth is you don't have to keep a whole thread running for that in the first place. You should use the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) so the function is only called when necessary, no matter what function made the actual update. Your `get_staff_list` should listen to the event, from the program startup, and your several button "callbacks" functions should themselves emit this event, which will trigger the function listening to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's a awesome knowledge for me